# Symfony3.2 Cotroller factory

Tags: controller, routes, symfony, factory

I have problem with Symfony. I'm trying to use factory for controller, but it doesn't work.

```
#services.yml    
services:
          app.foo_controller_factory:
            class: Foo\Controller\DefaultControllerFactory
            arguments:
              container: '@service_container'
          app.foo_controller:
            class: Foo\Controller\DefaultController
            factory_class: '@app.foo_controller_factory'
            factory_method: create_service

#/routing.yml
foo_bar:
  path: /foo
  defaults: { _controller: app.foo_controller:indexAction }
```

The problem is because application never goes trough DefaultControllerFactory.

What could be the solution?

Comment: Switch to development mode.  The error messages will give you a hint.

Comment: It's actually a bit interesting.  factory_class and factory method were removed in S3 but rather than throwing an error the framework just creates the controller without using the factory.  In any event, replace the factory_ with factory: ['@app.foo_controller_factory', 'create_service'] http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html

Comment: Thank you @Cerad!!! Your proposal helped.

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify services.yml

```
#services.yml
services:
  app.foo_controller_factory:
    class: Foo\BarBundle\Controller\DefaultControllerFactory
    arguments:
      container: '@service_container'
  app.foo_controller:
    class: Foo\BarBundle\Controller\DefaultController
    factory: 'app.foo_controller_factory:createService'
```